# Java ActionListener Return Variable To Method That Contains ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, return, listener

I have a method like so, which is given an array of `JButton` and returns their text whenever they are pressed:

```
public static String foo(JButton[] buttons) {
    for (JButton i : buttons) {
        i.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                return i.getText();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But, of course, this code will not compile because I am returning a variable to a null method. So, how would I have `i.getText()` return its output too the `foo()` method?

---

**Edit**, all of the code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class JCustomFrame {
    public static void showMessageFrame(String title, String message,
            String[] textOnButtons, ImageIcon icon) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);

        JLabel messageLabel = new JLabel(message);
        messageLabel.setFont(messageLabel.getFont().deriveFont(16.0f));

        panel.add(messageLabel, c);

        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridx = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < textOnButtons.length; i++) {
            JButton button = new JButton(textOnButtons[i]);
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    return ((JButton) arg0.getSource()).getText();
                    frame.dispose();
                }
            });
            button.setFont(button.getFont().deriveFont(16.0f));
            panel.add(button, c);
            c.gridx++;
        }

        if (icon == null) {
            frame.setIconImage(new BufferedImage(1, 1,
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE));
        } else {
            frame.setIconImage(icon.getImage());
        }
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setTitle(title);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JCustomFrame.showMessageFrame("Test Frame",
                "Do you really want to do this?", new String[] { "Hell No",
                        "Sure, Why Not" }, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're thinking in a linear/procedural fashion, this isn't how UIs work, UIs are event driven, meaning something happens (at some point in time) and you respond to it. There's no point retiring the value back to the foo method, because the code will have completed executing long before the ActionListener was notified. Better to have the listener perform the required actions itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This statement doesn't make sense:

> So, how would I have i.getText() return its output too the foo() method?

The method `foo()` is no longer running after the ActionListeners have been added to the buttons, and certainly will have ended by the time a user pushes a button, as per the rules of event-driven programming. Instead, though you could have the ActionListeners change the state of a class, any class, and that should suffice. For instance:

```
class FooClass {
    private String text;

    public void foo(JButton[] buttons) {
        for (JButton i : buttons) {
            i.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    text = e.getActionCommand(); 
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

If you need greater detail on a viable solution, please tell us more details about your actual program and your specific problem.

Now if you actually needed a method to return the value of the button pressed, you would need to do this via notification mechanisms and a call-back method, but again the details of a solution will depend on the details of the actual problem and code.

---

**Edit**

You're trying to emulate a JOptionPane. Your solution is to either use a JOptionPane, adding a JPanel to it, or create your own using a modal JDialog:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JCustomFrame2 {

   public static String showMessageFrame(Window owner, String title,
         String message, String[] textOnButtons, ImageIcon icon) {
      final JDialog dialog = new JDialog(owner);
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

      // make it application modal!
      dialog.setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();

      panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

      GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
      c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
      c.fill = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
      c.gridx = 0;
      c.gridy = 0;
      c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);

      JLabel messageLabel = new JLabel(message);
      messageLabel.setFont(messageLabel.getFont().deriveFont(16.0f));

      panel.add(messageLabel, c);

      c.gridy = 1;
      c.gridx = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < textOnButtons.length; i++) {
         JButton button = new JButton(textOnButtons[i]);
         button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener(sb));
         button.setFont(button.getFont().deriveFont(16.0f));
         panel.add(button, c);
         c.gridx++;
      }

      if (icon == null) {
         dialog.setIconImage(new BufferedImage(1, 1,
               BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE));
      } else {
         dialog.setIconImage(icon.getImage());
      }
      dialog.add(panel);
      dialog.setTitle(title);
      dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      dialog.pack();
      dialog.setVisible(true);

      return sb.toString();
   }

   private static class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
      private StringBuilder sb;

      public ButtonListener(StringBuilder sb) {
         this.sb = sb;
      }


      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         sb.append(e.getActionCommand());
         Component component = (Component) e.getSource();
         Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(component);
         if (win != null) {
            win.dispose();
         }
      }
   }

   public static String showMessageFrame(String title,
         String message, String[] textOnButtons, ImageIcon icon) {
      return showMessageFrame(null, title, message, textOnButtons, icon);
   }


   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String result = JCustomFrame2.showMessageFrame("Test Frame",
            "Do you really want to do this?", new String[] { "Hell No",
                  "Sure, Why Not" }, null);

      System.out.println(result);
   }
}
```

Comment: @LucasBaizer: that should be posted with your question. I've taken the liberty of doing this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated? whatever `foo` is supposed to do, it would be a lot easier to simply call another method from inside the `ActionListener` with the name of the button as argument. Or, if you really want to achieve something like this, make the thread wait for the user to press a button.

```
public void doSomething(){
    JButton[] someButtons = ...;//whereever you create the buttons

    System.out.println(foo(someButtons));
}

public static String foo(JButton[] buttons){
    final String someString = "";

    final Object lock = new Object();

    for(JButton b : buttons){
        b.addActionListener(e -> {
             someString.concat(b.getName());

             synchronized(lock){
                 lock.notifyAll();
             }
        });
    }

    synchronized(lock){
        try{
            lock.wait();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){}
    }

    return someString;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but what is `synchronized`?

Comment: It's used to lock a block of code with the specified object. This prevents multiple threads from accessing the same piece of code on the same object at once. That's just a cooked down version though. It's described more precisely here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html (for synchronized methods) and here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html (for synchronized statements)

Comment: Have you tested this in a running program? It looks like it risks locking the entire GUI if not done extremely carefully and mostly in a background thread.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels depends upon where `foo` is called. It shouldn't be called from within the event processing thread, but if this is ensured, the GUI will work just fine. And as far as i can see, OP wants to use it in the main-thread, so everythings fine

Comment: If foo is called from the EDT, this will block the EDT, meaning the ActionListenr will never be called, if not called from the EDT, then you run the risk of a race condition with the EDT...

Comment: *"As far as I can see, the OP wants to use it in the main-thread" - which is more likely a understanding on the ops behave then a conscious design decision

Comment: To simplify this discussion: i've presented another solution aswell and made clear it would be preferable to the solution using concurrency.